# Prove a subgroup is normal in $S_n$

Tags: group-theory

Given $S_n,$ the permutation group, and $\sigma$ a permutation represented as a $n-$cycle, we define the subgroup $H: = \langle\sigma\rangle.$ Given that the order of $\sigma$ is $n$, we may claim $H = \{ \sigma^0, \sigma^1, ..., \sigma^{n-1} \}.$ I need to prove that $H$ is normal in $S_n.$ Let $\tau \in S_n.$ We need to prove $\tau \sigma^k \tau^{-1} \in H \,\forall \sigma^k \in H.$ How can I go from here ? I am wondering if a $n-$cycle commutes. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Why are you trying to prove something that is not true?

Comment: Since $\tau\sigma^k\tau^{-1}=(\tau\sigma\tau^{-1})^k,$ no need to consider $σ^k.$ The subgroup $H$ is normal iff $\forall \tau\in S_n\quad\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}\in H.$ This was just a general remark, which may be useful in other circumstances. But not here because anyway, for $n\ge4,$ $H$ is not normal, since the number of conjugates of $\sigma$ (i.e. of $n$-cycles) is $(n-1)!>n.$

Comment: @Anne Bauval. Thanks. How do you find that the number of $n-$cycles, i.e. the number of conjugates of $\sigma$ is $(n-1)!$ ?

Comment: When choosing an $n$-cycle $\rho,$ there are $n-1$ possible choices for $\rho(1)$ ($\ne1$),  then $n-2$ possible choices for $\rho^2(1)$ ($\ne1,\rho(1)$), and so on.

Comment: Thanks. But I can not explain the case $n = 3$ since $(3-1)! = 3$ does not hold even though $H = <123>$ is normal in $S_3.$ Can you comment on that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $S_4$ and $\sigma = (1234)$. Just for clarity, we have $H = \{id, (1234), (13)(24), (1432)\}$. Now, take $\tau = (12)$, then $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1} = (1342)\not\in H$.

Answer (score 2):

In any group, a subgroup is normal if and only if it is a union of conjugacy classes. For the $4$-cycles in $S_4$ this gives a conjugacy class of $6$ elements in $S_4$, and not $3$ (plus the class with the identity with $1$ element). So a subgroup of order $4$ in $S_4$ generated by a $4$-cycle cannot be normal. For $n=3$, though, it is true. Then also $H=\langle (123)\rangle$ has index $2$ in $S_3$ and hence is normal.